# My code passes validation, but runs very slowly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_password_good(password):
    if len(txt) > 7 and [i for i in txt if i.isupper()] and [i for i in txt if i.islower() and [i for i in txt if i.isnumeric()]]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

txt = input()

print(is_password_good(txt))
```

Comment: You are looping over `txt` 3 times. Instead of putting everything in 1 line, try a more verbose loop, loop only once, and do all the checks on each pass.

Comment: While the code could be optimized, there is no reason why it should be so slow it could be observed. So, what does "very slow" mean?

Comment: Also, you are building possibly large lists for the sole purpose of determining if the list is empty or not. Use `any` and a generator expression so that you only need to find *one* such `i` which would guaranteed a list length of at least 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running three `for` loops, one after the other, when you could run a single `for` loop:

```py
def is_password_good(password, good_length):
    if len(password) < good_length:
        return False

    has_upper, has_lower, has_digit = False, False, False
    for char in set(password):
        has_upper = char.isupper() or has_upper
        has_lower = char.islower() or has_lower
        has_digit = char.isdigit() or has_digit
        if has_upper and has_lower and has_digit:
            return True
    return False
```

Imagine a password of all lowercase letters -- you have to check every one to see if you also get a digit or uppercase letter, therefore you will iterate over all `n` *unique* characters before you can say definitively that the password does not satisfy the requirements. This means that in the worst-case scenario, the best you can possibly do is `O(n)` (again, where `n` is the number of *unique* characters in the string).

The idea then should be to break out of the loop *as soon as possible* -- in this instance, once all three flags have been switched to `True`.

Each of the three `char.isxxx() or has_xxx` statements will be `True` forever once the first time the check is satisfied, since after the first time it is `True`, the statement reduces to `char.isxxx() or True` which will always be true.

Once all three flags are set, you can break and then return whether `good_length` is satisfied as well.

Comment: I really liked this option. I'll try to revise my code for a better perception.

Comment: @Alexander don't forget to accept an answer so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a capital letter, using the method you're using, every letter is going to be evaluated.  So if you have 50 letters in your string, and you're using the list comprehension method, you're going to do 50 things per list.  And in your case, there are three list comprehensions, so there will be `len(txt) * 3` evaluations made everytime.

Using your method, modified with the password inline to make the timeit call simpler:

```
import timeit

def is_password_good():
    txt = "Sup3rlongpassword"
    if (
        len(txt) > 7
        and [i for i in txt if i.isupper()]
        and [i for i in txt if i.islower() and [i for i in txt if i.isnumeric()]]
    ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> timeit.timeit(is_password_good)
17.099690434522927
```

Here's a method using regular expressions.  In each case, as soon as the passing condition is met, it will return the value.

```
import re 

has_upper = re.compile('[A-Z]').search
has_lower = re.compile('[a-z]').search
has_digit = re.compile('[0-9]').search    

def is_password_good_re():
    txt = "Sup3rlongpassword"
    if len(txt) > 7 and has_upper(txt) and has_lower(txt) and has_digit(txt):
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> timeit.timeit(is_password_good_re)
0.8171015260741115
```

Edit:

Something else that stands out, one of your lists is nested within the other.

`[i for i in txt if i.islower() and [i for i in txt if i.isnumeric()]]`

So this means the numeric check is happening every character.  So if there are 10 characters in the password, there will be 10 checks for numbers, which involve 10 checks each, for a total of 100 evaluations for numbers alone.

Comment: Why not `return len(txt) > 7 and has_upper(txt) and has_lower(txt) and has_digit(txt)`?

Comment: I was sticking to the basic structure of the OP's code example.  Your suggestion is indeed more concise.

Comment: Thank you. Using regular expressions really looks better.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate with each `method` being your condition, and break when the condition is met to save resources.

```py
def is_password_good(password):
    if len(password) > 7:
        password = set(password)
        for method in (str.isupper,
                       str.islower,
                       str.isnumeric):
            for i in password:
                if method(i):
                    break
            else:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

```py
>>> is_password_good('1234567')
False
>>> is_password_good('12345678')
False
>>> is_password_good('123456aa')
False
>>> is_password_good('123456aB')
True
```

This method:

- Breaks when the condition is met

  - To avoid wasting compute time checking an answer that is proven correct
- Has a space complexity of `O(<=n)`

  - Converting to `set` removed duplicate letters
- Is scaleable for more functions

  - Just add another `lambda` function to the `method` tuple

Comment: Fixing now, just realised

Comment: it is false for all condiiton plus a character cant be upper lower and digit at same time

Comment: Also, just return the value that comes back from `any`, which is already going to be either `True` or `False`.

Comment: @ddejohn fixed. see update

Comment: Thanks, lambda functions are not too clear to me yet. But I think it's a great option that I'll come back to later.

Comment: You can do `for method in (str.isupper, str,islower, str.isdigit)` -- no need for lambdas. Also, In the worst case, with a password of `n` unique characters and `m` methods, it'll be `O(n*m)` which is the same as OP's code.

Comment: @ddejohn, thanks. I meant *space* complexity not time (I changed it).

Comment: @ddejohn, Is it even possible to improve on a worst case `n * m` time?

Comment: There's a difference between iterating over `n` items `m` times and performing one constant time operation on each pass, versus iterating over `n` items once and performing `m` constant time operations,